# BIG QUERY SQL: Trying to run a CASE STATEMENT IN SQL and getting this error: Syntax error: Expected keyword ELSE or keyword END but got "," at [2:109]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, syntax-error, case

In each of these categories, I am trying to create a case statement over has this escape character. Need some help finding out how to bypass this.

```sql
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN category = "IAB1,IAB19,IAB9_1" THEN "Arts & Entertainment, Technology & Computing, Art/Technology",
     WHEN category = "IAB1,IAB9,IAB9_30,IAB9_7" THEN "Arts & Entertainment, Hobbies & Interests, Video & Computer Games, Card Games",
     WHEN category = "IAB3,IAB9_30,IAB9_7" THEN "Business, Video & Computer Games, Card Games",
     WHEN category = "IAB9,IAB9_30,IAB9_7,IAB9_8" THEN "Hobbies & Interests, Video & Computer Games, Card Games, Chess",
     WHEN category = "IAB1,IAB9" THEN "Arts & Entertainment, Hobbies & Interests",
     WHEN category = "IAB1" THEN "Arts & Entertainment",
     WHEN category = "IAB9" THEN "Hobbies & Interests",
     WHEN category = "IAB9_7" THEN "Card Games",
     WHEN category = "IAB9_30" THEN "Video & Computer Games",
     WHEN category = "IAB9,IAB9_30" THEN "Hobbies & Interests, Video & Computer Games",
     WHEN category = "IAB1,IAB19,IAB9" THEN "Arts & Entertainment, Technology & Computing, Hobbies & Interests"
     ELSE  'Uncategorised' END AS IAB  
FROM `my_project.beeswax_20.beeswax-update`;
```

I was expecting it to return a table with all rows including the newly categorised column for the IAB codes in the image above.

Comment: Copy-paste your code here as text - no one will check your image. Next time someone posts a video here :(

Comment: Manage to paste the code above, thanks for looking out

Comment: just remove commas after each `WHEN ... THEN ...` block

Comment: In the case of `"IAB1,IAB9" THEN "Arts & Entertainment, Hobbies & Interests"` are you expecting data with the values `IAB1` AND `IAB9` to be flagged as "Arts & Entertainment, Hobbies & Interests"? Because currently the code is looking to match on exactly `"IAB1,IAB9"`?